# How to use implicit operator with preprocessor directives?

Tags: c#, .net-core, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a shared class library. So I want to create implicit operators accroding to platform. 
But this code isn't working.

```
using System;
using GTANetworkAPI;

namespace FoxRPShared.Utils {
    public class Vector3 {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;
        public Vector3() { }
        public Vector3(float x, float y, float z) {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }
#if SERVER
        public static implicit operator GTANetworkAPI.Vector3(Vector3 v) => new GTANetworkAPI.Vector3(v.X, v.Y, v.Z);
        public static implicit operator Vector3(GTANetworkAPI.Vector3 v) => new Vector3(v.X, v.Y, v.Z);
#else
        public static implicit operator RAGE.Vector3(Vector3 v) => new RAGE.Vector3(v.X, v.Y, v.Z);
        public static implicit operator Vector3(RAGE.Vector3 v) => new Vector3(v.X, v.Y, v.Z);
#endif
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error like `Cannot implicitly convert type "FoxRPShared.Utils.Vector3" to "GTANetworkAPI.Vector3".(CS0029)`
[image]
If I remove directives, code compiles.

Comment: Is `SERVER` defined? What line is reported by the error - one of the ones in this example, or somewhere else?

Comment: @JoeSewell yes, it is defined, i have tested it with some other methods. Error in antother line, where i m trying to use implicit operator. I will add it in the question

Comment: Do you have 2 compiled units (.dlls), one for the server and one for the client? The shared .dll is compiled with that directive enabled or disabled. Specifying `SERVER` in the dependent (non-shared) assembly (.dll/.exe) doesn't change anything to the shared .dll (its compiled already).

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. There is something other causing the issue. Does the error occur in the same assembly where the operators are defined?

Comment: @Caramiriel Oh, no, library with Vector class is not compiled to dll, because of I'm working on it, so in my server's csproj it is linked via  `<ProjectReference Include=....` and directive is defined with `<DefineConstants>SERVER</DefineConstants>`. But the problem is code of server doesn't compile at all, it is strange for me.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is, if the server specifies `<DefineConstants>SERVER</DefineConstants>`, the included project (via `<ProjectReference Include=...>`) doesn't receive this constant. You need to specify the constant where it's used (in this case the shared library). But then the client doesn't work anymore. Thats just the way preprocessor constants work.

Comment: @Caramiriel ok, thanks! I will take note. Seems like my problem with wrong project organization.